# Change ItemsControl ItemsTemplate based on data value

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have an ItemsControl bound to a Dictionary and am trying to apply a template based on the value of the Dictionaries key. I am trying to do:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=CommonItems, Mode=OneWay}">
    <ItemsControl.Style>
        <Style TargetType="ItemsControl">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Key}" Value="authentication">
                    <Setter Property="ItemTemplate" Value="{StaticResource AuthenticationTemplate}"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.Style>
</ItemsControl>
```

That doesn't work at all and my errors say Key doesn't exist on ItemsControl. That leads me to believe that It is using my TargetType to search for the binding. So how do I do this and have it actually use the ItemsSource?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do this per-item, i would suggest using an [`ItemTemplateSelector`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemtemplateselector.aspx).

Comment: Ok I saw that, but didn't know if I could just do it in XAML. I'll go ahead and use it thank you.

Comment: @twreid: You might be able to it in XAML as well, by using the `ItemContainerStyle` which styles the `ListBoxItems`. In the trigger you need to change the `ContentTemplate` (which is where the `ItemTemplate` should end up otherwise), also use a setter to set the default.